# A conditional retrograde analysis problem

Tags: problems, retrograde-analysis

Here is the problem-find a chess game that begins with 1. e4 and ends on the fifth move with knight takes rook mate, which determines who gives the mate.

This is a famous puzzle. For additional information and its history, see [this nice article](http://en.chessbase.com/post/the-infamous-1999-chebase-christmas-puzzle-160813) on ChessBase.

Comment: Maybe you should explain more clearly and/or extensively your question.

Comment: nice solution   etd

Comment: @ETD Is it possible to hide the solution (or write it in white color, so one does not see the solution unless one marks the text)? Just want to prevent people from accidentally seeing the solution and ruining an interesting puzzle for themselves.

Comment: @Zvonimir, now that the question is reopened, I posted a community wiki answer with the solution hidden, and will delete my comment that has the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ETD Very nicely done, thank you as well.

Answer (score 11):

The solution is as follows:

> 1.e4 Nf6 2.f3 Nxe4 3.Qe2 Ng3 4.Qxe7+ Qxe7+ 5.Kf2 Nxh1#